# How can I reset all public posts to be friends-only?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I recently found that despite my default posting privacy level being "friends" all of my recent posts are "public". Is there some way I can quickly move these posts back to "friends" or otherwise delete them without removing all my posts?

I turned off public subscriptions but I would rather make all the posts friends-only.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Click on the triangle in the upper right corner of the blue bar at the top of the window, then **Settings**, then **Privacy** in the left sidebar, and then **Limit Past Posts** on the right to expand that section.  Then click the **Limit Old Posts** button to limit your past posts to (at most) your friends.

You can also change the privacy setting on each post individually by clicking on the globe icon next to the public post.

[image: 2016 UI update]

Comment: I remember doing this previously when they changed the default privacy level on posts actually, but forgot where it was. Thanks!

Comment: Now if only Facebook's [API allowed this for posts that aren't "Public" but already "Friends" — does it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555091/does-the-facebook-api-allow-for-automated-changes-to-old-post-visibility)

Comment: I don't know if you're still reading this, but the interface seems to have changed since you posted this answer. Do you know what one does now, on the cusp of 2015? Thanks!

Comment: @jdc You can now go to Settings » Privacy » Limit Past Posts

Comment: This is awesome! I was afraid that it was going to take an entire evening, but it took less than a minute!