# How to limit old posts on Facebook to a custom friend list

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I'd like to know how to automatically assign the visibility of all my Facebook posts to, at most, a custom friend list. I know about the "Limit Old Posts" feature, and this does not allow you to select a friend list. Facebook has an API, does some 3rd party tool do this?

As of this moment, the only way I know to do this is manually, one post at a time. I have 7 years worth of posts. (It seems Facebook really doesn't want us to do this.)

This question is very related to [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27092/preventing-new-friends-from-seeing-old-facebook-posts). The conclusion there is that there is no automated solution.

Comment: To be honest, this is nigh unacceptable from Facebook. Adding this comment as a bump - hoping something's changed in the year since you posted it.